# Fixed-size form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I was testing my app, which uses a borderless form, and I accidentally maximised the wrong program, using WINDOWS + UP.

How can I stop my border-less from from being resized using the keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: Ctrl+Up does not do anything special.  I suppose you have some code you need to delete.  We can't see it.

Comment: I meant windows up, sorry--though, I have a feeling you knew that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set Maximum Size for your Form and it will not be maximized any more

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I just left it because I can't be bothered.